# Importing just one value with numpy.genfromtxt

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I would like to import just one value from a csv file. So far, I have been succesfull at using the skip_header and skip_footer options to seek out this element. It is a float value. One problem though, when I try to use this one element from my array, I get an error. Example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.genfromtxt('junker.txt',skip_header=6,skip_footer=7)
print x
```

returns

```
array(10)
```

however

```
print x[0]
```

returns

```
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

I just want to be able to use this value however I cannot because it's in a numpy array. Please help

Answer (score 1):

a numpy array in that form is actually just a number. For example:

```
x = np.array([1])
```

Has a length of 1. However your array does not. Being just a number, you may utilize it right away! Example

```
x = np.array(3)
y = x + 3
print y
```

Will yield 3.

The length of x will yield an error because while this is an array, it is technically a zero dimensional array. Hence a length cannot be recovered from this variable.

Comment: Strictly speaking it's a zero-dimensional array